# How can I make QtCreator compile with gsl library?

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator, gsl

I am trying to use the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/ in QtCreator. How can I tell Qt creator to add these flags: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linking-programs-with-the-library.html to link correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your .pro file and add the extra libs by hand, e.g.:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib example.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

See the [QMake](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .pro file and extra libs and include in windows:

```
 `win32{ 
   INCLUDEPATH += C:/gsl-1.11/include/ 
   INCLUDEPATH += C:/gsl-1.11/lib  
   LIBS += -LC:/gsl-1.11/bin -llibgsl-0 -llibgslcblas-0  
   }`
```

then the problem is solved